# Why does one menu item have a Hidden tag?

Tags: menu-item, tags

One of my menu items has a `hidden` tag on it. I don't recall seeing a setting or field for that. The menu item shows up on the site as expected. Why is it there and how might I have inadvertently placed it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option allows you to hide menu items in a rendered menu. This makes full ghost menus unnecessary.

[image]

https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/hide-menu-items/

Comment: Makes sense, but why is my menu item appearing on the site? Maybe it's a problem with the RocketTheme template.

Comment: If you don't use a 3rd-party menu module or a template overwrite for the Joomla menu module, the menu item shouldn't get rendered in the frontend if "display in menu" is set to "no". - tested in J3.8.7